# The power of a prime in the prime factorization of a factorial

Tags: prime-numbers, factorization

How do we find—for example—how many $5$s are in the prime factorization of $n!$?  I've read that it is $\lfloor n/5 \rfloor$, but why is that?

Comment: [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: It is not floor(n/5), of course.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy and well-known. I think it was known to Tschebycheff, and probably before.The (exponent in) the power of the prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is precisely $\frac{n - \sigma_{p}(n)}{p-1},$ where $\sigma_{p}(n)$ is the sum (in $\mathbb{Z}$) of the digits occurring in the base $p$ expansion of $n$. That is,
if $n = \sum_{j= 0}^{\infty} a_{j}p^{j}$ with $0 \leq a_{j} \leq p-1,$ then we have that $p^{\frac{n - \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{j}}{p-1}}$ is the precise power of $p$ dividing $n!$.

The answer you give for $p =5$ is not quite correct. The correct answer, known to Legendre and equivalent to that above is $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^{j}} \rfloor.$

As to the "why" part of the question, group theory can provide some insight (though the results can be prove arithmetically directly without using any group theory): when $n = p^{r}$ is a power of the prime $p,$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{n}$ is an $r$-fold iterated wreath product $C_{p} \wr C_{p} \wr \ldots \wr C_{p},$ and its order can be seen inductively to be $p^{ 1+p+ \ldots +p^{r-1}} = p^{\frac{p^{r}-1}{p-1}}.$

More generally, if we write $n = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{j}p^{j}$ in base $p$ as above, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{n}$ is isomorphic to a direct product over $j$ of a direct product of $a_{j}$ copies of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^{j}},$ leading to the first formula given above.